# Can anyone provide the source code for autohotkey implemented for opensuse linux written in java

Tags: autohotkey

Can anyone provide the source code for autohotkey implemented for opensuse linux written in java?? or can anyone help us in starting this project inopensuse??

Answer (score 2):

I believe the closest thing you will find is [IronAHK](http://www.ironahk.net/) which is a cross-platform rewrite of AutoHotkey written in C#.  The source code is located [here](https://github.com/polyethene/IronAHK), but the project seems to be rather abandoned.

Comment: IronAHK does run in Linux with mono, but it's incomplete and (AFAIK) doesn't have any GUI or hotkey capability. Another option is to run AHK under Wine. I've run short non-graphical scripts that way and even a few that pop up simple message boxes; but I fear that anything more involved probably won't work too well, as is the case with IronAHK.